# How can I change the chapter or section TOC's indentation without changing the main TOC indentation

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I was using TOC filed code with /b to create a TOC under Section 1 that only shows heading3 title and page numbers. But it always has 0.4" left indentation, how can I set zero indentation just for Section1 TOC, but still keep 0.4" left indentation in the main TOC. Also I want the Section1 TOC should still keep zero indentation after update TOC itself. Please click the picture link for details below.

Thanks.

[TOC Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1LnR.png)

Answer (score 0):

### In your secondary TOC field, set your Heading 3 to be reported as level 1 in that TOC.

[image: screenshot of dialog box]

This gives you a TOC field code of `TOC \h \z \t "Heading 3,1"`. This does not have the bookmark switch, which would also be needed.

The indentation is controlled by the TOC styles and changing a style for one TOC changes it for everything in the document. This uses the TOC 1 style for your Heading 3 entries in this TOC, instead of the TOC 3 style.

You can edit your current field to have the `"Heading 3,1"` setting.

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured out by using TC and assigned with a different TOC. I'll try your method later, see how it looks. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome.